# How to declare an array with type constraints?

Tags: swift

What I want it so to declare:

```
var types:Array<T.Type where T:Cacheable> = []
```

which stores T.self. But the syntax is wrong. What is the correct way? Thanks.

To make it more clear, here is a short description of what I wanna do:

```
protocol Cacheable {
    class func cacheKey() -> String
}

class User:Cacheable {
    class func cacheKey() -> String {
        return "user"
    }
}

class Post:Cacheable {
    class func cacheKey() -> String {
        return "post"
    }
}

func initTables(type: Cacheable.Type) {
    println(type.cacheKey()) // errors if use @Matt solution
}

func startup() {
    for type:Cacheable.Type in [User.self, Post.self] {
        initTables(type)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, now you've completely changed your question to an unrelated question. "Moving the goalposts", we call that... Next time, please _start_ by asking the question to which you _really_ want to know the answer, not some irrelevant, misleading question. - The reason for the _new_ problem is that you can't do what you're trying to do with a protocol; a protocol doesn't give you dynamic access to a class func. You have to use a Cacheable superclass; then you can call a class method that both subclasses inherit. I've edited my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it seems to work:

```
protocol Cacheable {}
struct S1 : Cacheable {}
struct S2 : Cacheable {}

var types : Array<Cacheable.Type> = []

// and this shows that we can actually store types in the array
types.append(S1)
types.append(S2)
```

And if you try to say something wrong like `types.append(String)` the compiler stops you and complains that String does not conform to Cacheable, which is exactly what we would wish it to say...!

---

**EDIT** Okay, so you've moved the goalposts on your question. It's an interesting new question, but it is a completely different question. The problem here is that a protocol is an "existential metatype", not a "metatype". You can't access a class function polymorphically through a protocol. You have to use a superclass instead. This works:

```
class Super {
    class func cacheKey() -> String {
        return "super"
    }
}

class User:Super {
    override class func cacheKey() -> String {
        return "user"
    }
}

class Post:Super {
    override class func cacheKey() -> String {
        return "post"
    }
}

func test() {
    for type : Super.Type in [User.self, Post.self] {
        println(type.cacheKey())
    }
}
```

So, if you have no other superclass for Post and User, give them an arbitrary superclass Super. If you *do* have a superclass for Post and User, then give that class a class func `cacheKey()` in an extension. Either way, you now have a polymorphic class func `cacheKey` which is what you are after.

---

However, your *real* question seems to be a third matter, namely how to arrive at a unique identifier for a class. There are probably better ways to do that than using a class func like this!

Comment: I also need call class function with the type parameter. So if I have User:Cacheable, when I pass in Cacheable.Type it cannot call class func because Cacheable.Type doesn't implement anything.

Comment: Please read my update. the println(type.cacheKey()) is the problem if I apply your solution.